# 2D physic, netplay with sync and not-sync bodies. Collisions

Tags: javascript, synchronization, box2d, game-physics

p2.js - physic 2d engine

let's say we have bodies that we synchronize through internet for netplay
but we have bodies that we don't synchronize as well, why?

for example for raindrops or some other particle effects.

Raindrops need to collide with ground and splash or something like that.
But they can't affect ground's body velocity, because it would make desync of netplay.

If not-sync body collide with sync body (raindrops vs uhm also moving lift up/down) all force that is produced needs to be applied to not-sync body (raindrops).

***The Question:***

How to make it happen in p2.js? (or even in box2d, maybe it will help too)

Dynamic body that has property (extended by me) property `.sync` set to false shall not affect body's velocity/position that has `.sync` set to true

Answer (score 0):

In p2.js engine just override this method:

```
p2.Equation.prototype.addToWlambda = function(deltalambda) {
  var bi = this.bodyA,
      bj = this.bodyB,
      invMassi = bi.invMassSolve,
      invMassj = bj.invMassSolve,
      invIi = bi.invInertiaSolve,
      invIj = bj.invInertiaSolve,
      G = this.G;

      //injection part
      if ( !bi.sync && bj.sync ) { //.sync is my field of Body "class"
        invMassj = 0;
        invIj = 0;
      }
      else if ( !bj.sync && bi.sync ) {
        invMassi = 0;
        invIi = 0;
      }
      //injection part end

  // v_lambda = G * inv(M) * delta_lambda

  addToVLambda(bi.vlambda, G[0], G[1], invMassi, deltalambda, bi.massMultiplier);
  bi.wlambda += invIi * G[2] * deltalambda;

  addToVLambda(bj.vlambda, G[3], G[4], invMassj, deltalambda, bj.massMultiplier);
  bj.wlambda += invIj * G[5] * deltalambda;
}
```

So far so good. For now it works.